# Redrawing heatmap on zoom in D3.js/v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a heatmap on D3.js v4 and I am trying to add zoom and panning feature to it. Zoom will only work on x axis and it will not change y axis. Parts related to zooming are below:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]).domain([minDate, maxDate]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
var zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 2])
             .translateExtent([[80, 20], [width, height]])
             .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
    xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x));
    svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    update();
}

function update() {
    svg.selectAll(".cell")
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#plotAreaClip)')
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.hour); })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return x(d3.timeWeek.offset(d.timestamp, 1)) - x(d.timestamp); })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d.hour + 1) - y(d.hour); })
        .attr("fill", function (d) { return colorScale(d.value); });
}
```

When I actually comment out `update()` in `zoomed()` function, I can see that axis zooms in/out just fine. But when `update()` is in the function, it just removes all rectangles in the chart.

JS Fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/7z1f4c5p/ (I don't know a way to upload csv file to JSFiddle so I had to write whole data to JS part. Sorry about that. Code is at the bottom. If you remove the comment on 97th line, zooming will not work.

Comment: The fiddle is missing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the new scale value in your `update()`.

```
function update() {
    // update: cache rescaleX value
    var rescaleX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x);
    svg.selectAll(".cell").attr('clip-path', 'url(#plotAreaClip)')
        // update: apply rescaleX value
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return rescaleX(d.timestamp);
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
            return y(d.hour);
        })
        // update: apply rescaleX value
        .attr("width", function(d) {
            return rescaleX(d3.timeWeek.offset(d.timestamp, 1)) - rescaleX(d.timestamp);
        }).attr("height", function(d) {
            return y(d.hour + 1) - y(d.hour);
        }).attr("fill", function(d) {
            return colorScale(d.value);
        });
}
```

looks like the the `rect` in `clipPath` does not have `width` and `height`.

```
// update: set widht and height of clippath rect
plotArea.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "plotAreaClip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
    //.attr({width: width, height: height});
```

Here's working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/7z1f4c5p/2/

You need to adjust the left and right space of the graph. Looks like it's a bit off when zooming.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to use `var rescaleX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x).clamp(true);` instead of `clipPath` though? It worked for me that way but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Visually they may look similar. The difference is with `clamp(true)` the output of the scale is forced to be within the range, in your case `[0, width]`. If you use clipPath, the output will be scale as it is. Anything outside of the clipPath will not be visible. Easy way to see this is inspect the element of the first rectangle in the graph. With `clamp(true)` the rectangle x is `0`. With `clipPath`, and NOT applying the `clamp(true)`, the x position is negative value, which will not be visible because it is outside the `clipPath` area and outside the limit of zoom extent.